# Does a page fault occur whenever we have a segmentation fault?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

Whenever a segmentation fault occurs, do we always have a page fault?

Anyone with linux kernel code experience can you pleas point the code here too?

I have already seen: [segmentation fault vs page fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950549/segmentation-fault-vs-page-fault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Segmentation fault can also occur under following circumstances:**

a) A buggy program / command, which can be only fixed by applying patch.

b) It can also appear when you try to access an array beyond the end of an array under C programming.

c) Inside a chrooted jail this can occur when critical shared libs, config file or /dev/ entry missing.

d) Sometime hardware or faulty memory or driver can also create problem.

e) Maintain suggested environment for all computer equipment (overheating can also generate this problem).

**Why page fault occur:**

a)Trying to access a virtual memory-address

b)Instruction-operand / instruction-address

c)Read-data/write-data, or fetch-instruction

d)Maybe page is ‘not present’

e)Maybe page is ‘not readable’

f)Maybe page is ‘not writable’

g)Maybe page is ‘not visible’

Comment: Cool, that's nice exhaustive list for both!

Answer (score 8):

Pagefault (aka #PF) is the common cause for **segfault** (addressing some data at a non-present page, trying to read or write data from a protected page without the according level of privilege, fetching code from a no-execute page, ...).

But segfault can occurs for some other rare reasons. For instance if you try to execute a privileged instruction without the requested *current privilege level* (CPL). Check this sample:

```
% cat segfault.c && gcc segfault.c -o segfault
int     main(void)
{
  __asm__("invd");

  return 0;
}

% ./segfault
Segmentation fault
```

In this sample, the **segfault** has nothing to do with memory. The `invd` instruction is a privileged one (only executable when the CPL is *ring0*). Thus you can't execute it from the *userspace*. When executing this instruction, a *general-protection fault* (aka #GP) exception happens. The kernel catch the exception and send the kill signal to the faulty program.

Comment: Thnx Benoit, this is the precise clarification I was looking forward to.